# aspnet core - browser not showing download progress on File result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, webapi

I have a simple web app which allows downloading files.
The file gets downloaded correctly, however the browser never indicates the amount of data received (i.e. the progress).

It just keeps showing 0.1 MB until suddenly the file is downloaded.
[image]

Download action is implemented as follows - for now, simply open-read the local file and return the stream as File result.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string id)
{
    var project = await this.service.GetById(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
    if (project == null)
    {
        return this.NotFound($"Project [{id}] does not exist");
    }
    var file = new FileInfo(project.DownloadLocation);
    this.Response.ContentLength = file.Length;
    return this.File(file.OpenRead(), "application/octet-stream", file.Name);
}
```

The download is triggered by a simple action link:

```
 <dd class="project-path">@Html.ActionLink("Here",  "Download", "Download", new { id = Model.Id})</dd>
```

Any idea why Chrome/Firefox never shows the download progress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should do the trick. You should try it with a larger file (eg:200mb)? It might be the reason time to calculate ETA taking more than downloading it in a local development environment.

Comment: Please notice that I am setting the content-length header manually - and it seems to 'work', because as soon as the download starts, the browser is aware that the total size will be 2.7 MB...

Comment: @Bartosz did you try it with a larger file (eg:200mb)? It might be the reason time to calculate ETA taking more than downloading it?

Comment: Surprisingly, larger file shows the progress... After around a minute or two of processing. Very weird, because the 2.7MB download also takes quite some time (around 40 seconds). Thanks!

Comment: Also, just for the record, returning '`this.File(System.File.IO.ReadAllBytes(path), "application/octet-stream", file.Name);` does not show the download bar at all until the download is done - i.e. it looks as if nothing happened for a longer while, and suddenly the file is ready.

Comment: Anyway, please update your answer to the actual solution (try larger file because code is fine) and I will accept it:)